# Joining two data frames on column name and comparing result side by side

Tags: pandas, numpy

I have two data frames which look like df1 and df2 below and I want to create df3 as shown.

I could do this using a left join to have all the rows in one dataframe and then did a numpy.where to see if they are matching or not.

I could get what I want but I feel there should be an elegant way of doing this which will eliminate renaming columns, reshuffling columns in dataframe and then using np.where.

Is there a better way to do this?

[image: Here I am left joining df1 on df2 to get df3]

code to reproduce dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd
df1=pd.DataFrame({'product':['apples','bananas','oranges','pineapples'],'price':[1,2,3,7],'quantity':[5,7,11,4]})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'product':['apples','bananas','oranges'],'price':[2,2,4],'quantity':[5,7,13]})
df3=pd.DataFrame({'product':['apples','bananas','oranges'],'price_df1':[1,2,3],'price_df2':[2,2,4],'price_match':['No','Yes','No'],'quantity':[5,7,11],'quantity_df2':[5,7,13],'quantity_match':['Yes','Yes','No']})
```

Comment: It would be nice if you add a reproducable example of the dataframes.

Comment: @sagi added code for reproduction.

Answer (score 0):

An elegant way to do your task is to:

- generate "partial" DataFrames from each source column,
- and then concatenate them.

The first step is to define a function to join 2 source columns and append "match" column:

```
def myJoin(s1, s2):
    rv = s1.to_frame().join(s2.to_frame(), how='inner',
        lsuffix='_df1', rsuffix='_df2')
    rv[s1.name + '_match'] = np.where(rv.iloc[:,0] == rv.iloc[:,1], 'Yes', 'No')
    return rv
```

Then, from *df1* and *df2*, generate 2 auxiliary DataFrames setting *product* as the index:

```
wrk1 = df1.set_index('product')
wrk2 = df2.set_index('product')
```

And the final step is:

```
result = pd.concat([ myJoin(wrk1[col], wrk2[col]) for col in wrk1.columns ], axis=1)\
    .reset_index()
```

Details:

- `for col in wrk1.columns` - generates names of columns to join.
- `myJoin(wrk1[col], wrk2[col])` - generates the partial result for this column from
  both source DataFrames.
- `[…]` - a list comprehension, collecting the above partial results in a list.
- `pd.concat(…)` - concatenates these partial results into the final result.
- `reset_index()` - converts the index (product names) into a regular column.

For your source data, the result is:

```
   product  price_df1  price_df2 price_match  quantity_df1  quantity_df2  quantity_match
0   apples          1          2          No             5             5             Yes 
1  bananas          2          2         Yes             7             7             Yes 
2  oranges          3          4          No            11            13              No
```

Comment: its a good answer but this needs me to use dictionary instead of dataframe for s1 and s2. I will see if I can improve this.